# Getting the page URL in a pages collection loop

Tags: handlebars.js, gruntjs, assemble

Im trying to build a dynamic menu to create a list of pages per tag. 
Is working fine except I don't know how to get the page url populated:

```
<section class="see-also">
{{#each tags}}
    <p>In <span class="tag">{{tag}}</span>:</p>
    {{#each pages}}
        <li><a href="#">{{data.title}}</a>{{pages.url}}</li>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</section>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@luis-martins you should be able to use the [relative helper](http://assemble.io/docs/helpers/helpers-path.html) with the destination from the current page being rendered and the destination from the current page in the `tags.pages` collection like this to generate a relative url:

```
<section class="see-also">
{{#each tags}}
    <p>In <span class="tag">{{tag}}</span>:</p>
    {{#each pages}}
        <li><a href="#">{{data.title}}</a>{{relative ../../page.dest dest}}</li>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</section>
```

Notice that to the the destination of the current page being rendered, you have to use the [parent syntax from handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths): `../../page.dest`. Also the `dest` property is on the current page item from the `tags.pages` collection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this looks correct to me. the built-in {{relative}} helper is the only way to get relative URLs from one page to another in the given context